# EHCache import not working after upgrading spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ehcache-3

EHCache configuration not working after upgrading `spring boot 3.0.2`

Below is the gradle dependency

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.image'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {  
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'
    implementation 'net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.9.1'
    
}
```

EHCache configuration Class

```
package com.image.cache.config;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;    
import net.sf.ehcache.Cache;
import net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration;

@Configuration
public class EhCacheConfig {

    @Bean
    EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    EhCacheCacheManager testEhCacheManager() throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(cacheManager().getObject());
    }

    private CacheConfiguration setCacheConfiguration(String cacheName) {
        CacheConfiguration cacheConfig = new CacheConfiguration()
                .eternal(false) // if true, timeouts are ignored
                .timeToIdleSeconds(3600) // time since last accessed before item is marked for removal
                .timeToLiveSeconds(3600 * 24) // time since inserted before item is marked for removal
                .maxEntriesLocalHeap(10000) // total items that can be stored in cache
                .memoryStoreEvictionPolicy("LRU") // eviction policy for when items exceed cache. LRU = Least Recently Used
                .name(cacheName);
        return cacheConfig;
    }

}
```

After upgrading to spring boot 3 getting below exception

```
The import org.springframework.cache.ehcache cannot be resolved
```

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes#:~:text=Ehcache%203.10,

Comment: Thanx for sharing the link.. But I am also facing issue in java code. Is there any changes required for fixing it?

Comment: Meaning in configuration file what changes need to be done for making it runnable

Comment: https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.3/migration-guide.html ;)

Comment: EhCache needs to be configured as a JCache provider instead of native EhCache. So in short remove that configuration and switch to the Cache API instead. \